# Uncertainties $\Delta r$ and $\Delta p_r$ for the hydrogenoid stationary states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, orbitals, quantum-states

I'm interested in the general formulas that give the *exact* uncertainties $\Delta r$ and $\Delta p_r$ (the *radial* momentum) for all stationary states $|n,l, m \rangle$ (or $\psi_{nlm}(r, \theta, \varphi)$), as functions of the quantum numbers $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \infty$ and $l = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1$.  The radial momentum hermitian operator I'm considering here is
$$
p_r = -\, i \hbar \, \frac{1}{r} \, \frac{\partial }{\partial r} (\, r \quad ) = -\, i \hbar \Bigl( \frac{\partial }{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r} \Bigr). \tag{1}
$$
This operator is hermitian: $p_r^{\dagger} = p_r$, and satisfies the usual commutator: $[r,  p_r] = i \hbar$, but may have a physical interpretation issue (see the comments below).

I'm able to calculate the uncertainties in the special case of $l = n - 1$ (since the Laguerre polynomials are just $L_0^k(u) = 1$ in this case):
\begin{align}
\Delta r &= \frac{n a}{2 \mathrm{Z}} \, \sqrt{2 n + 1}, \tag{2} \\[2ex]
\Delta p_r &= \frac{\mathrm{Z} \hbar}{n a} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 n - 1}}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
The Heisenberg relation is thus satisfied (of course):
$$\tag{4}
\Delta r \, \Delta p_r = \frac{\hbar}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{2 n + 1}{2 n - 1}} \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}.
$$
The equality is realized for $n \gg 1$.  But then, these expressions are only valid for $l = n - 1$.  What about the general case?

*Are the stationary states position and momentum **uncertainties** known as functions of $n$ and $l$?*

It's easy to calculate $\langle \, p_r \rangle$ for all stationary states $\psi_{n l m}(r, \theta, \varphi)$:
$$\tag{5}
\langle \, p_r \rangle = 0.
$$
But for $\langle \, p_r^2 \rangle$, it's much harder because of the Laguerre polynomials.  I can only show this integral (from an integration by parts.  $\phi_{n l}(r)$ is the radial part of the atomic wave function):
$$\tag{6}
\langle \, p_r^2 \rangle = \hbar^2 \int_0^{\infty} \Bigl( \frac{d\, }{d r} \bigl( r \, \phi_{n l}(r) \bigr) \Bigr)^{2} \, dr.
$$

The comments below are objecting that the radial momentum (1) isn't a good observable because of the spectral decomposition issue.  But then, the operator $p_r^2$ is showing in the atomic Hamiltonian, which is a good Hermitian operator associated to a well behaved observable.  So while $p_r$ may be problematic as an observable, $p_r^2$ isn't.  What I'm interested in is the average (6), so this is a perfectly valid question.  I guess the simplest way to get (6) is to find $\langle \, r^{-1} \rangle$ and $\langle \, r^{-2} \rangle$ (for a general stationary state $|n, l, m \rangle$) and to substract their contributions to the energy levels:
$$\tag{7}
\frac{1}{2 m} \langle \, p_r^2 \rangle = E_n - \frac{\hbar^2 \, l (l + 1)}{2 m} \langle \, r^{-2} \rangle + k \mathrm{Z} e^2 \langle \, r^{-1} \rangle.
$$
So the question remains the same and I think the objections below are irrelevant.

Comment: The actual definition of $p_r$ is quite tricky (and IIRC it’s not even necessarily self-adjoint) so you should at least provide a definition of $p_r$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, I'll add a comment about it, but it's a standard hermitian operator.

Comment: Well, one could also think about $p_r:=-i\partial_r$ (which is not hermitian), so the comment of @ZeroTheHero very well applies.

Comment: The radial momentum does **not** admit a spectral measure since it does not admit selfadjoint extensions. It is therefore disputable the physical meaning of things like $\Delta p_r$…See, e.g., arxiv:math-ph/0009016

Comment: @ValterMoretti, the radial momentum is part of the Hamiltonian (more specifically its square $p_r^2$), and the important thing is that the integrals do converge to define a meaningful $\Delta p_r$.

Comment: There is no projector valued measure to define it, so any computation is arbitrary and may have no physical meaning. There are positive operator valued measures which can be used however. Presumably some implicit choice is made in computation.

Comment: The situation is similar but worse that the momentum in a box: there there are infinitely many selfadjoint extensions here none.

Comment: @ValterMoretti, could you give a good reference (from arXiv) about this state of affaire, apart of **arxiv:math-ph/0009016**?  I'm not sure that this paper was peer reviewed.

Comment: That paper is publushed in J. Phys A. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/35/16/311/pdf

Comment: Your definition of radial momentum does not seem hermitian to me: $\left(i \hbar \frac{1}{r}\right)^\dagger = -i \hbar \frac{1}{r}$. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @SmallPieceOfBread, the radial momentum is not just $-\, i \hbar \, \frac{1}{r}$.  You need the full (4).  It is Hermitian (it is well known), but it is not **self-adjoint** (which isn't the same as **Hermitian**, but don't ask me why).

Comment: So you want a generic expression involving generalized Laguerres?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, yes, I'm interested in $\Delta p_r$ as a function of $n$ and $l$, despite the ambiguity of $p_r$ as a physical observable.  I was able to find it only for $l = n - 1$ (expression (2)).  I know that $\langle \, p_r \rangle = 0$ for a general $\psi_{n l m}(r, \theta, \varphi)$ (the integral is easy to do in this case).

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't cast that, although I really should. It is still not clear if you are asking for a bunch of integrals, some of which you surely could carry out yourself!, or a deeper issue of principle.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, as I said in the question, it is the integral (5) that's hard to evaluate, to get $\Delta p_r$.  More specifically, I'm asking if the quantities $\Delta r$ and $\Delta p_r$ were already computed and shown somewhere.

Comment: Compendius of generalized Laguerre integrals might exist and be discoverable. You have explored *l=n-2* next?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found what I was looking for :
\begin{align}
\Delta r \equiv \sqrt{\langle \, r^2 \rangle - \langle \, r \, \rangle^2} &= \frac{n a}{2 \mathrm{Z}} \sqrt{n^2 + 2 - \Bigl( \frac{l (l + 1)}{n} \Bigr)^2}, \tag{A} \\[2ex]
\Delta p_r \equiv \sqrt{\langle \, p_r^2 \rangle - \langle \, p_r \rangle^2} &= \frac{\hbar \mathrm{Z}}{n a} \sqrt{1 - \frac{2 \, l (l + 1)}{n \, (2 l + 1)}}, \tag{B}
\end{align}
where $\langle \, p_r \rangle = 0$ for all stationary states $|n, l, m \rangle$.  Despite that the Hermitian operator $p_r$ has issues, $p_r^2$ doesn't and is perfectly well defined as an observable.  Formulas (2) and (3) are special cases of (A) and (B) (their minimal value for a given $n$), for $l_{\text{max}} = n - 1$.  The maximal spread is found for $l_{\text{min}} = 0$.